# Topic clarification: Native Linux tablets

Tags: discussion, scope

I wanted to know if the following question was on topic here. I asked this on SU somewhile back and it was closed as off topic. The revisions of the question are [here](https://superuser.com/posts/676348/revisions), below is the original question:

---

### Does there exist a tablet that will run linux natively?

I don't need recommendations, I just wanted to know if there exists a tablet that runs or can run linux natively (not sandboxed in the host os) with documented confirmation, and/or instructions.

Let me be crystal clear: I'm not talking about Android tablets. If you answer this question by saying Android IS Linux I will downvote your answer into oblivion (I suspect those will be comments now). It's fine if it's an Android tablet with documented instructions on installing Linux and removing Android, but I'm not referring to running Linux Deploy within Android, for example.

I don't care about a specific distro at this point, although I am partial to debian based distros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course a Q&A site about `Unix & Linux` might include people that know an answer to your question, but that is not the criterion on which to judge whether the question is appropriate here or not.

I would vote to close¹ such a question as off-topic as it doesn't seem to match any of the [topics you can ask about on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you decide to post here, including which of the categories as mentioned in the help you think this your question matches would of course be possible (and if you can't find a matching one, you should be able to draw your own conclusions).

¹ <sub>If posted with the wording of the original question, I would also downvote into oblivion.</sub>

Comment: [This meta question](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600/hardware-recommendations-whats-the-limit) one upvoted answer which states that `Hardware recommendation questions that have very specific requirements that aren't easily solved by checking the vendor-listed information or official hardware compatibility lists should be allowed.` Most vendors don't outright list that you can install $distro on $tablet. I'm not asking *where* to buy, or looking to outright compare, but I believe this is a question which cannot be easily answered by google at the moment.

Comment: @BigHomie shopping recommendations are explicitly off-topic. it doesn't matter if it can't be found with Google; those kinds of questions just do not fit the SE model. instead, try: "what should I look for in a tablet to determine if I can get GNU/Linux onto it?" or something to that effect